# Splitting field of $x^8-1$ over $\mathbb{F}_2 ,\mathbb{F}_3,\mathbb{F}_{16}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials, splitting-field

Find the splitting field of $f(x)=x^8-1$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$, $\mathbb{F}_3$ and $\mathbb{F}_{16}$.

**I tried this:** We claim that the field with $q=p^m$ elements is unique. A field with $q$ elements is the smallest field containing $\mathbb{F}_p$ and all the roots of $x^q−x$. Such a field is termed a splitting field of the polynomial $x^q−x$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$, that is, the smallest extension field of $\mathbb{F}_p$ containing all the roots of the polynomial. So, $x^9-x$ is of the form $x^{3^2}-x$, hence the splitting field is $\mathbb{F}_9[x]=\dfrac{\mathbb{F}_3[x]}{\left (x^2+1\right )}$. On the other hand, we know that the splitting field of $f(x)=x^8-1$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$ is of the form $\mathbb{F}_{q^t}$, where $q^t\equiv 1\pmod n$, so in this example $2^t\equiv 1\pmod 8$, which is impossible. And I don't know how to find the splitting field over $\mathbb{F}_{16}$.

Comment: In any field of characteristic $2$, $x^8-1=(x-1)^8$ is reducible, so the splitting field is the original field.

Comment: @Zerox I don't get it, so it means that it can't be factored over $2^4=16$ or it can but it's the same as $\mathbb{F}_2$

Comment: What I meant is, $x^8-1$ has all its roots (in fact, one root of $8$-th order) in $\Bbb{F}_2 \subseteq \Bbb{F}_{16}$, so its splitting field does not add anything in **both** cases.